# I'm leaving Germany for 5 months on Erasmus exchange, how can I have unemployment benefits and insurance paid?

Tags: germany, health-insurance, students, unemployment-benefits, erasmus

My contract will be over in February, because I will move to Portugal to begin my ERASMUS mobility. I need to know how can I receive unemployment benefits (I will have worked on a contract for 24 months by that time), because I will be jobless and won't be able to work because of my full time studies, but will definitely need the money for those months (to pay the insurance, that I understand I would have to pay myself otherwise) and to go back to Germany in July and keep receiving the unemployment benefit there.

Any advise? Should I request ALG I and then fill the U2 document?

Comment: You are only eligible for unemployment benefits if you are available to the (German) job market. Hence, I'm afraid that you cannot receive neither ALG or ALG2 during your stay in Portugal. That's not only because you'll be in Portugal but more generelly because you are enrolled as a student. There are only very few cases where students are eligible for unemployment benefits.

Comment: @erc Generaly this is true. But for projects that are supported by the Job Center, there are exceptions. That is why the OP should report his **Erasmus** activity to the Job Center so that he may be insured during that time (if supported) and apon return (when he is fully available) the ALG will start.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Why and in what way would Erasmus plus be supported by the Job Center?

Comment: @erc The why: because a betterment of the professional qualifications i, under certain conditions, supported by the Job Center. The what: depends on the circumstances. See links in my answer.

Comment: @erc In general, transfer to another EU member state ought to be possible (that's what the U2 document is about) but looking for work would typically still be a requirement. I think the exact requirement would depend on Portuguese (and not German) law.

Answer (score 1):

> because I will move to Portugal to begin my ERASMUS mobility.

What form of contract for the Erasmus do you have?

If you are not being sponsored by a school (where you would then be insured), then you should go **now** (with your present and Erasmus contracts) to the [Job Center](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/bildung/studium/wege-ins-ausland-im-studium) to work out the details. There is also a [Eurasmus+](https://www.erasmusplus.de/) program to assist a "Freemover", that is otherwise not covered.

The Job Centre should assist you in getting everything properly prepared (including the unemployment after your return) before you leave. This, however, must be applied for in a *timely manner*.

---

**Sources**:

- [Krankenversicherung für Studenten aus dem EU-Ausland - Krankenkassen.de](https://www.krankenkassen.de/meine-krankenkasse/student/ehic/)
- [Wege ins Ausland im Studium - Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/bildung/studium/wege-ins-ausland-im-studium)

  - [Startseite - Erasmus+](https://www.erasmusplus.de/)